# Geeetech A10M extrusion issues

Tags: troubleshooting, underextrusion

So I purchased a Geeetech A10M a while back and have never been able to get it to print right. I own two other Ender 3's and have been printing for about 4 years now. I fix most issues myself but this has stumped me.

The printer just seems to print "OK" at the start but then starts under extruding. Stringing is also really bad, but the stock cooling is garbage. I've tried new filament as well as different brands with no prevail. I've changed my slicer settings what feels like a billion times. I am unsure if the unique Y-splitter hot end is causing a problem. I've also never used Titan-style extruders and am unsure if those are a problem. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

I use Cura as my slicer. I started with the preset profile already there, and then I edited it as I began having issues. I've tweaked just about everything I can think of in the slicer. I want to like the printer. It's just that it prints like crap right now. This printer is my personal project of sorts so it isn't really bugging me. But the end goal is obviously to get it to print good!

For now the specs of the printer, these will be updated with the values used for the prints from the photos:

- Filament diameter: 1.75 mm
- Nozzle diameter: 0.4 mm
- Retraction 10 mm
- Temperatures:

  - End 200 °C
  - Bed 60 °C
- Speed 60 mm/s
- Infill 20 % Rectangular
- 6 top and bottom layers
- 5 perimeters
- 0.2 mm layer height
- Flow 100 %
- Travel speed 130 mm/s

[image: Photo of a printed model with printing issues]

[image: Another photo of a printed model with printing issues]

Comment: Okay, clearly an under-extrusion problem. The first layer is okay-ish but could improve. The retraction length is too long for the relative short Bowden tubes on the printer, try something in the region of 4-6 mm. Furthermore, the under extrusion worsens so beware of heat creep, force the cold end to br cooled properly. Also check the extrudes that they are not skipping. Fix this first and update the questions.

Comment: I have same problem the nozzle get clogged after while of extrusion, (Especially when used 2 extruders). Have you fixed this?